# CSS: select every odd DIV-only

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<h3>h3</h3>
<div>Content</div>
<h3>h3</h3>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<h3>h3</h3>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<h3>h3</h3>
<div>Content</div>
...
```

I would like to select every second div (ignoring the h3s). Is that possible with CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you even try to search? searching your exact question on google has the answer on first link

Comment: @TylerH: I am sure this is a dupe but don't think it is a dupe of the one linked. `nth-child()` won't work here.

Comment: @Harry: I've been itching to give my answer to that question a makeover anyway, so I've gone ahead and done that now as well as adding details for nth-of-type. But I reopened this anyway - it is indeed a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nth-of-type(even)`

```css
div:nth-of-type(even) {
    color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<h3>h3</h3>
<div>Content</div>
<h3>h3</h3>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<h3>h3</h3>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<h3>h3</h3>
<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it with nth-child (which wasn't working obviously) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on the parent wrapper.

```
div:nth-child(even) {

    //code here
}
```

Comment: This won't quite do what OP is asking. It will select every other div, starting at 1, because the first appearing `div` is the *second* child.